# What is the best usb wireless adaptor to use with Kali Linux that works well with aircrack-ng?

Tags: kali-linux

I have Kali Linux installed on my laptop as a dual boot with Windows 8.1 and the pci wireless adaptor inside of my laptop (Broadcom 802.11ac) apparently is not compatible with either as I've spend weeks trying to find any information on how to get it to work. So I decided it would just be easier to order a usb adaptor from amazon and I was wondering if anyone had experience with this and knew which would be a good adaptor that is relatively inexpensive that I can rely on.
Thanks!
-Cade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend going to the air-crack site as they have a great section on picking an adapter.  [Here](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatible_cards) is the link.

It comes down to a number of factors; price, compatibility etc.  If you follow that guide you should be a able to find a great adapter that works for aircrack for you!

My personal preference is below :)

1. AWUS036H – (Bigger size) $24.99
2. AWUS036EW – (Smaller size) $19.97

[image: Here is a picture of the one I have, it works great and allows for external antennas that you can add on later for greater range]

Here is a picture of the one I have, it works great and allows for external antennas that you can add on later for greater range.  It also has native linux support and requires no patching for packet injection.  Works "out of the box!!!!!"

Comment: Thanks!:) I researched it a little bit more and I think the AWUS036H will be perfect for me and I just ordered it on amazon!

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider :

TP-LINK TL-WN722N 150Mbps High Gain Wireless USB Adapter = £12

http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-LINK-TL-WN722N-150Mbps-Wireless-Adapter/dp/B002SZEOLG?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00

but the Alfa is the best :-)